# Variable lost in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm facing a strange behaviour when trying to pass a variable as parameter to a nested ajax request callback:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    })
    e.preventDefault(e);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:dest_url,
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                // performing some actions
                // at this point, data.id contains my id

                // We call an other function, 
                // which performs an other ajax request, 
                // with data.id as parameter

                listRefresh(data.id);

            }else{
                // error message
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            // error message
        }
    })
});


function listRefresh(id){
    console.log(id); // At this point, id contains my id
    $.ajaxSetup({
        header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    })
    var src_url = location.href + '?id='+id;
    $.ajax({
        url: location.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function(id) {
        console.log(id); 

        // At this point the console outputs 
        // all my html code in place of id

        // I tried to pass data, response, id, but still the same issue
    })
    .fail(function() {
        //error message
    });
}
```

As said in code comments above, in the listRefresh ajax done callback, my variable seems to disapear and the console.log outputs my entire html code in the console...
I've never seen something like this. Do you have an explanation of why, and how could I pass my id as parameter to the ajax callback ?

Comment: Without seeing the backend code, I think you want `url: src_url` instead of `url: location.href`. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're expecting - you're just making a GET request to the current page and dump out what comes back, which is just your HTML.

Comment: @Quasdunk, thanks but it is normal, I use src_url below but I didn't paste my entire code. My problem is solved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of the `.done()` method is the response of the AJAX call. If your call returned a HTML page, the `id` variable got all of the html string assigned to it.

To keep the id in its variable simply use another one like:

```
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  console.log(id); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument passed to the function in `done` is the response from the AJAX request.  It doesn't matter what you *call* the variable, that's what will be passed to that function.

You can capture the value in the closure however, simply give it another name and assign it to a local variable.  Something like this:

```
done(function(response) {
    var theId = id;

    // "response" contains the response from the server.
    // "theId" contains the value of `id` from outside this function.
})
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Also I may be wrong but wouldn't you simply be able to continue calling it id? In op's code the only reason id doesn't work is because he is effectively overwriting that name with the value of his ajax response.

Comment: @Robbie Milejczak Yes indeed, my problem is solved, you were both right, and I did use id in my script without reaffecting it.